# Determine and print the smallest and largest values contained in 99-element floating-point array

Tags: javascript, html

Determine and print the smallest and largest values contained in 99-element floating-point array.  Using notepad++, it doesn't give any errors.  If something is wrong, it just won't show anything.  This is what I have, but obviously not right.  Any suggestions please?

```
var w = new Array ( 99 );

parseFloat (smallest) = 0;

parseFloat (largest) = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i , 99; ++i )

{

    if w[i] < smallest
       smallest = w[i];
    if w[i] > largest
       largest = w[i];
}

document.writeln( "The smallest number is: " + smallest);

document.writeln( "The largest number is: " + largest);
```

Comment: What do you intend for `parseFloat (smallest) = 0` to do?

Comment: You've created an array with 50 elements, but all of them are, so far, `undefined`.

Comment: is this wrong : `for ( int i = 0; i , 99; ++i )`; try this : `for ( int i = 0; i < 99; ++i )`

Comment: I was trying to make it read as a number instead of a string so it can be compared.  I am not sure about this floating point.  That means that decimals can be read correct?  How do I only have 50 elements?  Please elaborate?  & I'm sure they are undefined, not exactly sure how to do it without typing in 99 random numbers.  I meant for it to be <, oops.

Comment: should be using var instead of int: `for ( var i = 0; i < 99; ++i )`

Comment: So the question you're trying to ask is: "*how do I find the minimum, and maximum, numbers from the array of numbers?*"

Comment: You'd have errors in your browser console or wherever you're trying to run this code

Comment: Yes, from an array that has to be created I guess?

Comment: When I open it in my web browser & something is incorrect, the screen shows blank.  When I have the code correct, it shows up as it should.  Notebook ++ doesn't have a run program like eclipse does.

Comment: To see the browser's error console, run the JavaScript in the browser and press 'F12' button.

Comment: Beware, Internet Explorer is not the best browser for debugging JavaScript. Try Google Chrome or FireFox. Personally I prefer Google Chrome :)

Comment: @david, now that's a good work! and no need to entertain a duplicate question anymore